# Unable to add subtotals in RDL (SSRS 2008) with xml data source

Tags: xml, wcf, ssrs-2008

I have used WCF as data source to my report file. I have bind the dataset to my report.
But when try to add subtotal or use SUM() in a cloumn of the tablix then while preview my report that column show "#Error" while all other columns gets filled with the data binded.
Please help me to add subtotals in RDL (SSRS 2008) with xml data source.
[image]

In the image "#Error" appears when i use SUM()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason behind this is that when we bind xml data with rdl file then it donot implesitly identify the datatype of the data. It assume data as string.

So in order to apply aggregation function in report we will have to explicitly convert it into the relavent datatype.

For Example: =SUM(**CDec**(Fields!Amount.Value))